# Laravel and vue.js template: javascript handled as literal instead of being executed

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

I've a **home.blade.php** that ends with

```
@section('page_specific_scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        const slider_base_img_url = '{{ $slider_base_img_url }}'
    </script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/home.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

This is the relevant part of **home.js**

```
Vue.component('slide', Vue.Slide);
Vue.component('carousel', Vue.Carousel);

const slider_app = new Vue({
    el: '#home-page-slider',
    template: `
        <carousel :perPage="1" :autoplay="true"  :autoplayLoop="true" >

            <slide v-for="n in 3">
                <IMG
                    class='autosize'
                    src="{{ slider_base_img_url + '0' + n + '.png' }}"
            />
            </slide>
        </carousel>
    `
});
```

And this is my **mix** config file

```
mix
    .js('resources/assets/js/home.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['vue', 'lodash', 'vue-resource', 'vue-carousel'])
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss', 'public/css/vendor')
    .version();
```

The problem is that vue templates is rendered but the src of the image remain the textual javascript. This is the **generated HTML**

```
<div class="VueCarousel-inner" style="transform: translateX(-3806px); transition: transform 0.5s ease; flex-basis: 1903px; visibility: visible;">

<div class="VueCarousel-slide">
<img src="{{ slider_base_img_url + '0' + n + '.png' }}" class="autosize"></div>

... [cut] ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, this is the **home.js file after mix** as loaded from the browser

```
Vue.component('slide', Vue.Slide);
Vue.component('carousel', Vue.Carousel);


var slider_app = new Vue({
    el: '#home-page-slider',
    //language=HTML
    template: "\n        <carousel :perPage=\"1\" :autoplay=\"true\"  :autoplayLoop=\"true\" >\n           \n            <slide v-for=\"n in 3\">\n                <IMG\n                    class='autosize'\n                    src=\"{{ slider_base_img_url + '0' + n + '.png' }}\"\n                />\n            </slide>\n        </carousel>\n    "
});
```

*The template itself is working, because the for loop creates 3 slides*.

**But why the inner javascript is not being executed?**

Is there a specific Vue-way that actually I don't know yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done this 2 modifications, and now works:

this **in home.blade.php**

```
@section('page_specific_scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.slider_base_img_url = '{{ $slider_base_img_url }}'
    </script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/home.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

and this is **home.js**

```
const slider_app = new Vue({
    el: '#home-page-slider',
    //language=HTML
    computed: {
        slider_base_img_url: function () { return window.slider_base_img_url; }
    },
    template: `
        <carousel :perPage="1" :autoplay="true"  :autoplayLoop="true" >

            <slide v-for="n in 3" :key="n">
                <IMG
                    class='autosize'
                    :src="slider_base_img_url + '0' + n + '.png'"
                />
            </slide>
        </carousel>
    `
});
```